# Failed lookup for key [last_published_by_user] in Page <> while trying to run export aging_pages in Wagtail 2.16.2

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

On the page specified in the error I can see there is a user_id associated with the pageLogEntry table.

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/core/utils.py", line 351, in multigetattr
current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('Page' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/core/utils.py", line 356, in multigetattr
current = getattr(current, bit)

During handling of the above exception ('Page' object has no attribute 'last_published_by_user'), another exception occurred:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/core/utils.py", line 362, in multigetattr
current = current[int(bit)]

During handling of the above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'last_published_by_user'), another exception occurred:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/**init**.py", line 125, in wrapper
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 195, in decorated_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/reports/base.py", line 41, in get
return self.as_spreadsheet(self.object_list, self.request.GET.get("export"))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/mixins.py", line 259, in as_spreadsheet
return self.write_xlsx_response(queryset)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/mixins.py", line 241, in write_xlsx_response
self.write_xlsx(queryset, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/mixins.py", line 230, in write_xlsx
self.write_xlsx_row(worksheet, self.to_row_dict(item), row_number + 1)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/mixins.py", line 148, in to_row_dict
row_dict = OrderedDict(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/mixins.py", line 149, in 
(field, multigetattr(item, field)) for field in self.list_export
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/core/utils.py", line 369, in multigetattr
raise AttributeError(

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/reports/aging-pages/
Exception Value: Failed lookup for key [last_published_by_user] in <>